# What are the methods used to measure the concentrations of these anions?

Tags: equilibrium, experimental-chemistry, concentration

Chromate and dichromate anions has the following equilibrium in acidic solution:

$$\ce{2CrO4^2- + 2H3O+ <=> Cr2O7^2- + 3H2O}$$

How can one experimentally measure the concentration of each ion at a certain equilibrium?

Comment: pH indicators come to mind.  More elaborate techniques could include conductivity measurements, NMR measurements, density measurements, etc.

Comment: Surely the simplest way is UV-vis spectroscopy, unless the peaks overlap significantly.

Comment: certainly don't try spectrophotometry, I did that in an experiment and my results were atrocious, and this is the main reason why I am asking. The difference in peak wavelengths was about 5nm

Comment: O17 NMR seems to be a thing and should work.  Cr53... possibly two, but unclear. However at elevated temperature chromate/bichromate conversion may become too fast for distinguishable peaks to exist.